# Bacon Avocado as Root Stock

Tags: avocado, plant-hardiness

Living in New Zealand, we have very limited choices of avocados.  I've recently come across a new type - "Hayes" - which has been grafted on to Bacon rootstock.

Does anyone know how water/phytophthora tolerant Bacon root stock would be compared with Zutano?

Similarly does anyone know how frost tolerant Hayes avocados are?  (We get a few nights a year where temperature falls to low negative centigrade - coldest I've recorded is -6°C (but over the last 2 years only -3°C, and only shortly after dawn).)

Comment: @VividD - if you're going to create new Tags, please make sure you spell the word correctly - it was incorrect in the question, and you just created a tag with the same, incorrect spelling

Comment: @bamboo I didn't create any tag - 'plant-hardiness' is an existing tag, and btw its spelling is correct; you probably mistaked me with another person.. :) ; also, I did not create 'phytophthora' tag, with or without correct spelling, but this flag is removed now I believe; 'avocado, I also did not create, but its spelling is correct as far I can tell - so, what tag I created with wrong spelling??

Comment: @VividD phytothera - I edited it out of your re-edit, the other tags are fine

Comment: @Bamboo - If you look at the history of edits for this question, you will be able to see that this tag is created by davidgo - and not by me.

Comment: @VividD ah, well if that's the case (I don't have time to check now) my apologies

Comment: @bamboo It takes 15 second to check!? But you have time to make accusations...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68721/discussion-between-bamboo-and-vividd).